# Transform a minimization problem to LP

Tags: optimization

This is a past examination question. I was asked (Q.1) to find an equivalent linear programming problem of:

$$\min_{x \geq 0} \left \|Ax-a \right\|_{1}  + \left\|Bx-b \right\|_{\infty}$$

where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$; $B$ is an $l \times n$ matrix, $b$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{l}$.

(Q.2) I need to give the KKT conditions of the problem.

(Q.3) I need to formulate the problem to a linear variational inequality.

---

My puzzle for (Q.1) is about the two different norms used in the minimization problem. Is it a linear programming problem already? Would you please teach me how to do (Q.1)?

I think I can finish (Q.2) if my problem of (Q.1) is solved.

For (Q.3), would you please give me hint to finish it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean that $B$ is an $l\times n$ matrix?

Comment: @alethiometryst thanks. I modified it.